# creating session keys on javascript requests

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, session, uploadify

so this may have something to do with my JS request being from uploadify, but basically what i want to do is on an uploadify JS request, i want to set a session value.  this does not seem to work.

however when i make an HTML request, it does.

i have uploadify passing my session key and value through as a parameter with the request... is there something i need to do with it to authenticate and set the session?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, unfortunately its a bit tricky but totally possible.

First you will need a non-cookie store session.  If you are using a cookie store session you will need to switch to a database/memcache/redis or similar session store.

How sessions normally work is that rails give you a cookie with a session id.  When your browser makes a normal request it sends the cookies to rails, and rails therefore knows immediately which session to look for in its database, finds it, and loads it into session[].

When your using uploadify or similar techniques, the request does not have the cookie data sent with it, therefore rails has no idea who is making the request, and making the whole session stuff not work at all.

So the way to fix it is to have uploadify send the session id as a parameter, which sounds like what you may be doing, but then you need to add some Rack Middleware to the mix.

The Rack Middleware is basically a layer that sits inbetween the initial request and rails, and it will look at the parameters, and if it sees a session_id in the normal http parameters, it will turn this into what looks like a cookie, before it gets to rails.  So essentially rails thinks it is a normal user with a normal cookie, then all session stuff starts to work, and rails can know who is making the request.

There is quite a few examples of these online so rather than re-writing I will just link:

http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/07/21/uploadify-and-rails23/

http://metautonomo.us/2010/07/09/uploadify-and-rails-3/

Good Luck!

Comment: so i have had the middleware in place per the examples, and has been generating the proper session information, but why would this not work with using a cookie store session?  if the middleware is generating a valid cookie, wouldn't any session store method work?  it even looks like all the examples are using cookie store sessions.

Comment: there maybe some way to get it to work with a cookie store, but my understanding of why it wont work is that in the cookie store, the client (browser) sends ALL the session data to the server (encoded of course) with each request.  there is no way to have the uploadify accomplish this that I am aware of.  instead with database sessions, the client is only sending the session id, and its the servers responsibility to look up the session data on its end.

Comment: hmm... the only cookie data that is stored is the session key/value, and that is being passed in as a parameter from uploadify.  the middleware is setting it as a cookie as it should.  aside from the session data, what other data would be needed?